# Mapping a userId to it's associated email

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I run the following command in the Console it returns a column titled "userId". How do I map this userId to its email address or username?

```
<REDACTED>@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ bq show \ 
--transfer_config \
projects/<XXX>/locations/europe/transferConfigs/<XXX>
```

The returned value for userID is a 19-character integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run :

```
$ gcloud auth list
```

and it will give you the the user you and service account you are logged into .

Edit:

```
$ gcloud iam service-accounts list
```

[will list all service accounts in project](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/iam/service-accounts/list)
    and

```
$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID
```

[will show members in the output](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/projects/get-iam-policy)

Comment: This command will only display the email address of the logged in user. I want the userId of all users that have access to a specific project.

Comment: Yes of course, could you edit the question then? It's unclear what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. The `gcloud iam service-accounts list` command lists the account name and email, it does not include userId. Adding `--verbosity none` does not result in any additional returned columns. I don't currently have permission to run the last command, let me see what I can do.

Comment: Edited my answer a bit. 
userids as you say (emails) of users will show up in the members field in gcloud projects get-iam-policy 

ex: gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID |grep user:

Comment: Are you implying userId's are emails? Because I don't think this is the case, the command in my question returns a userId column that is an integer so clearly not an email address.

Comment: I must have misunderstood your request. The 3 commands I gave above are GCP project specific and will list the users who are either Google groups, users or service accounts  who have access to your project.  If your question is BigQuery specific, here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs#TransferConfig this shows the UserID field is deprecated and may be a legacy output that you probably cannot map to any real accounts. You could also post on stackoverflow.com with tag google-bigquery to confirm

Comment: Thanks or posting that link, yes it looks like my question is specific to Bigquery so I've asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196507/mapping-a-userid-to-its-associated-email).